# Should I make those links no follow or do follow?

Tags: seo, nofollow, dofollow

Post Title : Top 10 WordPress Custom Post Type Tutorials

I am going to link 10 WordPress custom post type tutorials blog posts which I found from the internet in to the above post.

Should I make those links no follow or do follow?

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked many times in various forms. You will find a endless supply of no follow related questions by using the Pro Webmasters search feature i.e: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nofollow+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that occasion, the answer is to use the follow / don't do nothing.

If the content you're creating is a decent piece of legit, original content, you should insert your sources or link to relevant pieces using a normal link and not even thinking about it.

I normally only use nofollow in situations like:

1. Paid Links;
2. Comments;
3. Something not generated by you (imagine your users can create posts).

Other than this, you shouldn't worry that much with the type of link.

There are some situations that might require special attention, like Links in Widgets, take a look at what [Matt Cuts says about the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvR_8aGEc98).

And the official [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) position:

> **How does Google handle nofollowed links?**
>
> In general, we don't follow them. This means that Google does not
>   transfer PageRank or anchor text across these links. Essentially,
>   using nofollow causes us to drop the target links from our overall
>   graph of the web. However, the target pages may still appear in our
>   index if other sites link to them without using nofollow, or if the
>   URLs are submitted to Google in a Sitemap. Also, it's important to
>   note that other search engines may handle nofollow in slightly
>   different ways.

Here's some good reads about this:

http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2013/07/24/follow-nofollow-links

http://searchengineland.com/infographic-nofollow-tag-172157